# Htaccess file erased

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, .htaccess

I needed to add a line of code to my htaccess file so I downloaded it by FTP using Filezilla to my local machine

I now see that the size of the htaccess file on the server is now 0 while the one I downloaded to my machine is not

Seeing this issue is tried to upload the htaccess file back to the server from my local machine but it does not work and it gives the below error

Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (87,76,19,25,195,177).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD
Response:   226 Transfer complete
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Type set to A
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (87,76,19,25,195,149).
Command:    STOR .htaccess
Response:   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for .htaccess
Response:   552 Transfer aborted. Disk quota exceeded
Error:          File transfer failed

I then tried to edit the empty htaccess file on the server to add in the code but when i click edit i get the below message

[image]

I have tried freeing up some disk space but yet the same issue persists

I would be extremely greatful for any help on how to restore this

Answer (score 0):

It's in the error message: "Disk quota exceeded Error: File transfer failed." Free up some disk space and you should be fine.

Comment: thank you for this, with regards to freeing up some disk space: I recently uploaded a lot of images to the media/import folder and they now show up for the products. Can i delete these images now from the import folder or will doing so delete the images from the products

Comment: You can delete from the import folder. It will not impact the product images

Comment: I have done this and the issue still persists it appears disk space is not the true error